# ArcGIS Experience builder - using dynamic text to populate feature values

Tags: arcgis-online, dynamic-text, arcgis-experience-builder

I'm switching from WAB to EB and rewriting a production app on the new platform. The legacy version has an option for a field user to to click a link underneath the attributes shown in a feature popup that autopopulates the value in a date field with the current date (this signifies the date the feature was visited in the field) saving the enduser a few seconds from having to choose from a calendar widget or manually type the date out. The client wants this functionality in the new version of the app.

Is it possible to have something like a side panel in EB that houses an editor widget checked for attribute editing and beneath it a card widget with a button containing  dynamic date syntax that points to the date field in the current feature attribute window in the editor widget? I've tinkered around a bit with it but EB froze on me after opening button widget. It seems maybe too black box for this type of customization.